# Angular - Displaying field from TMDB api

Tags: angular, themoviedb-api

Trying to display a field called certification from TMDB movie api, I am succeeded for all other information but not for this specific field :

Movie Component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {MoviesService} from '../movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.css']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  movie: Object;
  reviews: Array<Object>;
  similarMovies: Array<Object>;
  certification: Object;
  cast: Array<Object>;
  video: Object;
  constructor(
    private _moviesServices: MoviesService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this._moviesServices.getMovie(id).subscribe(movie => {
        this.movie = movie;
      });
      this._moviesServices.getMovieReviews(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.reviews = res.results;
      });
      this._moviesServices.getMovieCredits(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        res.cast = res.cast.filter((item) => {return item.profile_path});
        this.cast = res.cast.slice(0,8);
      });
      this._moviesServices.getMovieVideos(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        if(res.results && res.results.length) {
          this.video = res.results[0];        
          this.video['url'] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + this.video['key']);
        }
      });
      this._moviesServices.getSimilarMovies(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res.results);
        this.similarMovies = res.results.slice(0, 18);
      });
      this._moviesServices.getCertification(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res.results);
        this.certification = res.results;
      });
    })
  }

}
```

This is not working:

```
this._moviesServices.getCertification(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res.results);
        this.certification = res.results;
      });
```

html code:

```
<p class="badge badge-pill badge-success p-2" *ngIf="movie.certification">
        {{movie.certification }} 
      </p>
```

Movie Service:

```
getCertification(id: string) : Observable<any>  {
    const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('api_key', this.apikey);
    return this.http.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+ id +'/release_dates', {params})

  }
```

API URL: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/99/release_dates?api_key="my_api_key"

Comment: Can you show the component code

Comment: @ Jamie, yes i have updated the question with comonent code

Comment: can you make stackblits

Comment: Thanks, is there any errors in the console? Because the `movie.certification` would be a array of object, so to put it on the UI you would need to loop over the array.

Comment: Thanks! this is what it displays in console: 25: {iso_3166_1: "US", release_dates: 'Array(2)} and release_dates: Array(2)
0: {certification: "PG-13", iso_639_1: "en", note: "Dolby Theater", release_date: "2019-07-13T00:00:00.000Z", type: 1} ' this is what certification i want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the API documentation, the Release Dates endpoint returns a collection of release dates per country and each release date has a certification property.

So you really should do the following:

In your component change your `certification` property to a `Array<Object>`

and then in your HTML you are going to want to loop over the array and then loop over the `release_dates` array, since there is a certification per release date.

The below code I do not know if it will compile correctly, but it should give you an idea.

```
<p class="badge badge-pill badge-success p-2" *ngIf="certification">
    <span *ngFor="let cert of certification">
        <span *ngFor="let release of cert.release_dates"> 
            <span *ngIf="release.certification">{{release.certification}}</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

The above might not match your actual requirements, for example if you only wanted the certification for the US, then you should probably filter out the rest of the data in the component when you receive the data e.g.

```
this._moviesServices.getCertification(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
    const usCertifications = res.results.filter(result => {
        return result.iso_3166_1 === "US";
    };
    this.certification = usCertifications;
});
```

Comment: @ Jamie Thank you! I understand now and thanks for the html, now i am geting as array object in the console but just missing something to show them in ui side. do you think my service is fine? Here is the console result: (3) [ {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {iso_3166_1: "HU", release_dates: Array(1)}
1: {iso_3166_1: "AU", release_dates: Array(1)}
2: {iso_3166_1: "IE", release_dates: Array(1)}
3: {iso_3166_1: "US", release_dates: Array(1)}

Comment: The service is fine, it's getting the data, you just need to loop through the arrays. I've updated my example, but you can see you need to loop though the `certification` and then through the `release_dates` to get the `certification` for that release date

Comment: @ Jamie, Thank you so much for the prompt help, fixed now. Really appreciate it. :) Still trying to understand the migration from angular js to angular latest.